# Hide Column on Display, Show on Export ssrs

Tags: reporting-services

I want to Hide Column on Display, Show on excel Export SSRS
On visibility options,I have used expression

```
=IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "Excel", True,False)
```

But on preview it still appears.

Comment: Try renderformat.interactive instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just tested your expression on my machine. The reason why it doesnt work is because the value is case sensitive. To fix, right click the column you want to hide > Visibility > Show or hide based on an expression

Instead of:

```
=IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "Excel", True,False)
```

Use:

```
=IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "EXCEL", True,False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that the visibility description reads:

> Set expression for: Hidden

So having this evaluate to true when exporting to Excel will cause it to be hidden in that case.

Additionally, depending on the version of SSRS being used the Excel renderer may be for EXCEL or EXCELOPENXML.